# Find the joint distribution and covariance with exponential density

Tags: exponential-function, covariance, exponential-distribution, order-statistics, multivalued-functions

Let $X_1, \dots , X_n$ be independently distributed with exponential density
$$ f(x) = (2θ)^{−1}e^{−x/2θ},   x \geq 0 $$
and let the ordered $X$’s be denoted by $X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq \cdots \leq X_{(n)}$. It is assumed that $X_{(1)}$ becomes available first, then $X_{(2)}$, and so on, and that observation is continued until $X_{(r)}$ has been observed.

I try to find **the joint distribution of $X_{(1)}, \dots , X_{(r)}$** and **$\text{Cov}(X_{(r)}, X_{(s)})$ $(1 \leq r < s \leq n)$**.

I've been thinking all the way down to get the joint function, but I've been struggling ever since.

$$ f(X(1), . . . , X(r)) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} ... \int_{0}^{\infty} (2θ)^{−1}e^{−x/2θ} dx_1 dx_2 ... dx_n $$

I should like to have the benefit of your advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "becomes available first"?  The order statistics show up in a random order, the smallest value does not automatically show up first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density function for order statistics is complicated.  Probability texts such as Sheldon Ross' books give the formula and a short derivation.  Essentially the idea is to form the cdf first.  $P(X_{(k)} \leq c)$ = probability that $k$ variables are less and $n-k$ variables are more than $c$. I suggest using that breakdown.

Your joint pdf should have $(2\theta)^{-n}e^{-x
_1 /2\theta}e^{-x_2 /2\theta}...$